# BHO OnDocumentComplete for the top frame only?

Tags: c#, iframe, bho

I'm developing a BHO in CSHARP and I have  an issue in `onDocumentComplete` method.
It runs on every IFRAME that the main document loads. How can I avoid it? I only want to handle events in the main window.

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
  {
      document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;    
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare `this.site` with `pDisp`. If they're equal, then the code is running in the main frame:

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
    if (pDisp != this.site) {
        // Ignore subframes
        return;
    }
    document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;    
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: what is this.site?
i get the error that my project does not contain a definition for 'site' and no extension method 'site' accepting a first argument of type 'Greyhound.BHO.BHO' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user280109 The object that your SetSite method (that implements the IObjectWithSite interface) receives whenever the site changes.

Comment: i'm new to c# i see the site object in the setsite method, but i can't access it from the ondocumentcomplete method. do i need to make the variable a global somehow?

Comment: @user280109 You have store it as a member of your class instance.